# Did glaziers rescue medieval stained glass in World War II?

Tags: england, world-war-2, occupation, yorkshire

Does anyone out there have any information on glaziers rescuing medieval stained glass in World War II?  My grandfather William Manning was in this reserved occupation and I am trying to find out if he took glass from York Minster to slate mines in Wales for safety.  Where do I start?

Answer (score 3):

Start with York Minster and ask at their History / Conservation department [York Minster website](http://www.yorkminster.org/home.html). I believe that there is a City of London Guild for stained glass.

---

I have heard from my friend, that there is a City Guild and they have no records and are most unhelpful apparently. However, the Society of Master Glass Painters are helpful and have some records http://www.bsmgp.org.uk/.

Comment: I have heard from my friend, there is a City Guild and they have no records and are most unhelpful apparently. However, the Society of Master Glass Painters are helpful and have some records http://www.bsmgp.org.uk/.